# What is AppSite on Open Graph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Facebook states that it can read iOS App Link optional properties from Open Graph tags: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/article

Under the `al:iphone` tag, there is a required `al:iphone:url` property if I want to add an app link tag. However, I couldn't figure out what should this property be. I've tried to provide my app's App Store URL link at iTunes but Facebook Object Debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) tells me that the format is incorrect.

What should be the value of `al:iphone:url`?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's the app-specific-URL-scheme'd URL that will be opened when deep linking enabled. I've used the format `myappname://dosomething` and it worked.